# Tell nginx and/or php *not* to interpret commands per directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, php, nginx

I'm pentesting my new website, and used weevely to generate a php payload. I manually put it in the images directly where users will be able to upload images to my website. I'm able to establish a reverse connection to the weevely payload in `/images`. Is it possible to tell nginx and/or php *not* to interpret commands coming from the /images directory? Other than properly[1] coding a secure input mechanism with file validations, is there anything else we can do to prevent payloads from being executed in specific (/images) directories?

[1] https://php.earth/doc/security/uploading

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    charset utf-8;
    server_tokens  off;

    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name website.com;
    root /var/www/website/;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* .(png|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|css|html|txt|php)$ {
        expires 2d;
            add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST)$) {
         return 444;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear. What do you mean by "interpret commands". Nginx serves files and proxies requests to other servers or services, such as PHP. PHP runs scripts.

I think you want the images directory to just serve files, not run PHP scripts.

I've added my caching headers. Pragma is old, you don't need to use it.

```
location \images
   root \whatever;
   add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=691200, s-maxage=691200";
   more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Pragma"; more_clear_headers "Expires";
}
```

Alternately you can use something like the answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/227284/how-to-deny-access-to-php-files-inside-a-directory-nginx):

```
location ~ /images/(.+)\.php$ {
  deny all;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
  // as above
}
```